# What is this MOSFET circuit doing?

Tags: mosfet

[image: MOSFET circuit]

I am trying to figure out what this circuit does at the drain output of the MOSFET. How does the fet effect the circuit vs not having the components at all. The output goes directly to the processor and comparator.

Comment: What is off to the right of the circuit? What is it connected to?

Comment: The output is used for a comparator and as well as directly to the processor.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. It clamps the op-amp circuit output voltage at FET drain output voltage to ground for a short while after power-up. Why is a better question and you haven't provided any background info' at all. Please edit your question and add that detail.

Comment: What kind of input to the processor? What is the function of the input? What does the comparator do?

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like some sort of power on reset circuit.

At the instant power is applied to the circuit, both plates of the capacitor go to +5VA and switch on the FET which pulls the junction of the two resistors to ground. After a short time period, the capacitor will have charged which will turn the FET off, releasing the junction of the two resistors so that the op amp can have control over it. So the FET has no further function after a short time after power-up and is effectively disconnected from the circuit after it has provided that initial power up pulse.

Answer (score 1):

Note the bug in this circuit...

As the other answers say, the MOSFET gate is held high on power-on, turning the MOSFET on. One use for this circuit is in audio amplifiers, to mute the output and prevent loud **thump** noises on power-on. (It can also be used as a power-on reset to an MCU)

Now if you switch OFF, C256 remains charged up to 5V and will take some time to discharge...

So if you switch OFF and ON again reasonably quickly, **thump**.
(Or other adverse effect, like failure to reset the CPU after a power glitch)

The cure is a reverse biased diode across R313, so that if the 5V supply drops to 0, the capacitor is discharged, resetting the circuit for next time.

Answer (score 0):

At t=0, C256 is at zero volts.

When +5VA is applied, the voltage across C256 cannot change instantly. Thus, Q34 gate is pulled up to +5VA.

C256 then begins charging through R313, and the gate voltage drops.

So it acts as a power-on switch, which resets after a certain amount of time.